# UITextView doesn't show until it is scrolled

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview, uitextview

I am using a `UITextView` to display the text from a `xml`.I parsed the xml and stored the text in a `NSArray` and from there i am adding it to a `UITextview` in my code.

problem:
When i run the code the textview shows as empty or with partial text,and when i try to scroll the textview the whole text is getting displayed.

I added the `UITextview` to a `UIView`.

i found it strange and googled it but could not find many answers which helps me.
Can someone reply me to solve the issue

TNQ

Comment: Have you checked that your UItextView has the frame you expect (you can set its background color to make quick visual checks)

Comment: I also faced this issue. I resolved this issue using this solution.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11147954/1635315

Answer (score 10):

Found a simple SOLUTION

Had the same problem. When you put text into a UITextView which is not visible, it doesn't draw the text.

I had my UITextView off screen and animated it in like this:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    self.contentView.center = CGPointMake(self.contentView.center.x + move * (self.contentView.frame.size.width /2), self.contentView.center.y);
    self.textView.frame = self.textView.frame; // <<<--- ADD THIS LINE
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished) {
    }
}];
```

When you re-set the textview's frame, it re-draws it's text. So all you need to do is add the line I marked above before your UITextView comes on screen.

Cheers

Comment: +1 This totally sucks to have to do this, but this definitely solved my issue.

Comment: In my case I needed to first set it to CGRectZero, then restore it. Man!

Answer (score 5):

UITextView inherits from UIScrollView, so just scroll it.

```
[detailsTextView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 1) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

i solved the issue by clearing the textview and added the text to the textview again,i dont know the exact funda but my issue is solved.
in my case:
i am changing the frame of the textview from outside to the view on click of a button.while the button is clicked the textview is not showing content and on scroll it shows.

i solved, by deleting the text from textview and re entering the text on clicking the button.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue right now. I start off with the UITextView off screen and then slide it in with the push of a button. I loaded the textview with text (more than 10 lines) but it's not diplayed until the user touches the textview. This looks like a iOS bug, or weird "feature". Doing the above fix only makes the first line visible... duh.

Answer (score 0):

`UItextView` inherits from `UIScrollView`. That means it has scrolling functionality. Thus, if the contents of the `UITextView` is small enough to fit in its frame, it doesn't need to scroll.

But, if it is large enough, you need to scroll the `UITextView`.

Does this makes sense?

For more information, refer the class reference of [UITextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html)

Comment: that is true,but my case is that the uitextView is not showing any data before it is scrolled .Atleast it should the amount of data that fits in the textview before it is scrolled.isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that, method in which u set textview's text is call properly.And string which u assign to text view is in proper string format(if not so retain it).

Answer (score 0):

There are chances that the *whitespaces* and/or *newlines* are there before the actual text. Trim those characters before you assign it to text view.

```
NSCharacterSet *charset = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
NSString *text = [parsedString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charset];
textview.text = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it when your textView is loading

```
NSAttributedString *oldtext = objTextView.attributedText;
[objTextView removeFromSuperview];
objTextView.attributedText = oldtext;
[self.view addSubview:objTextView];
```

In my case my text is attributed

Answer (score 0):

When you complete the operation which parses the XML are you ensuring that your update is occuring on the main thread ?

UIKit only updates on the main thread so any updates made off it will only show up next time you touch the object and force an update.

As an example of one way to do it correctly.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

   [self parseXMLOffMainThread];

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

      self.myTextView.text = parsedText;

      });        

 });
```